# Wiremock request matching with dynamic date - How to check a date in test?

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, wiremock

I need to check in my test, that the date in request is exactly Today.
How can I do this? Tried different ways from the Doc, but haven't got the desired result.
Help please a poor junior qa :)

What way I tried (my collegue advised me this one, and it looks rather ok consider the documentation)

```
{
    "request": {
        "urlPath": "/test/calc",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": {
                "equalTo": "application/json"
            },
            "Content-Type": {
                "equalTo": "application/json"
            }
        },
        "bodyPatterns": [
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": {
                    "expression": "$.addDate",
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "before": "now + 1 days"
                        },
                        {
                            "after": "now - 1 days"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "equalToJson": {
                    "RequestBody": {
                        "order": {
                            "positionList": [
                                {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "addDate": "${json-unit.any-string}",
                                    "qty": 1
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ignoreArrayOrder": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "transformers": [
            "response-template"
        ],
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "v1/test-service-mock-response.json",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check parameter "addDate" in request. Date format is = "addDate": "2022-03-31".

*Also tried this variant "addDate": "{{now format='yyyy-MM-dd'}}". It didn't work as well
Wiremock didn't match such requests.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I wanted to do the same: match a request based on a dynamic date value in the request body.

Your question did point me in the right direction and I managed to get it working by combining multiple bodyPatterns. In your case the following should work:

```
    "bodyPatterns": [ {
      "matchesJsonPath": {
        "expression": "$.RequestBody.order.positionList[0].addDate",
        "and": [
          {
            "matches": "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"
          },
          {
            "equalToDateTime": "now",
            "truncateExpected": "first hour of day"
          }
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "equalToJson": {
        "RequestBody": {
          "order": {
            "positionList": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "addDate": "${json-unit.any-string}",
                "qty": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ignoreArrayOrder": false
    } ],
```

The first `bodyPattern` uses the `expression` in `matchesJsonPath` to find the `addDate` field (for simplicity only checks the first element of the array because that is enough for your usecase) and checks if it is in the right format and equal to the current date.

The second `bodyPattern` is basically what you already had and uses `equalToJson` to match the rest of the request body and only checks if `addDate` is a string.